# read whole settings section instead of one by one

Tags: c#, settings, app-config

I have a app.config looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<appSettings>
    <add key="Setting1" value="value1" />
    <add key="Setting2" value="value2" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Is it possible to somehow read the whole section of settings? Instead of just calling them one by one:

```
private static readonly string Setting1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Setting1"];
private static readonly int Setting2 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Setting2"];
```

Is that possible? If not by this way, how should I achieve this (was thinking about creating an own Settings.xml but I wanna try this first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just directly use the object returned by `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`: it has a whole load of [other members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

eg.

```
var as = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
foreach (string k in as.AllKeys) {
  Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", k, as[k]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me!

Comment: is it possible to name the section somehow?

Comment: @emptyman You can create custom configuration sections – a large part of the `System.Configuration` is all about that – but that is a completely different question (and these days the MSDN examples, eg. [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), are actually useful).